# Data Preparation In R

Tags: r, grepl

I have six .txt datasets files i've stored at '../data/csv'. All the datasets have similar structure(X1(speech),part(part of the speech i.e Charlotte_part_1 ...Charlotte_part_60)). Am having trouble combining all the six datasets into a single `.csv` file called `biden.csv` which has speech, part,location, event and date  .But am having trouble extracting the  speech, part(this two are from the file content) and event(from file name) of the file names because of their varying naming structure.

The six datasets

```
 "Charlotte_Sep23_2020_Racial_Equity_Discussion-1.txt",
 "Cleveland_Sep30_2020_Whistle_Stop_Tour.txt",
 "Milwaukee_Aug20_2020_Democratic_National_Convention.txt",
 "Philadelphia_Sep20_2020_SCOTUS.txt",
 "Washington_Sep26_2020_US_Conference_of_Mayors.txt",
 "Wilmington_Nov25_2020_Thanksgiving.txt"
```

Sample content from 'Charlotte_Sep23_2020_Racial_Equity_Discussion-1.txt'

```
X1 part
"Folks, thanks for taking the time to be here today. I really appreciate it. And we even have an astronaut in our house and I tell you what, that’s pretty cool. Look, first of all, I want to thank Chris and the mayor for being here, and all of you for being here. You know, these are tough times. Over 200,000 Americans have passed away. Over 200,000, and the number is still rising. The impact on communities is bad across the board, but particularly bad for African-American communities. Almost four times as likely, three times as likely to catch the disease, COVID, and when it’s caught, twice as likely to die as white Americans. It’s sort of emblematic of the inequality that exists and the circumstances that exist." Charlotte_part_1
"One of the things that really matters to me, is we could do … It didn’t have to be this bad. You have 30 million people on unemployment, you have 20 million people figuring whether or not they can pay their mortgage payment this month, and what they’re going to be able to do or not do as the consequence of that, and you’ve got millions of people who are worried that they’re going to be thrown out in the street because they can’t pay their rent. Although they’ve been given a reprieve for three months, but they have to pay double the next three months when it comes around." Charlotte_part_2
```

Here is the code i have designed but its not producing the output i wan't...i mean it just creat the tibble with the tittles but no contents in any of the variables

```
biden_data <- tibble()  # initialize empty tibble

# loop through all text files in the specified directory
for (file in list.files(path="./data/csv", pattern='*.txt', full.names=T)){
  filename <- strsplit(file, "[./]")[[1]][5]  # extract file name from path
  
  # extract location from file name
  location <- strsplit(filename, split='_')[[1]][1]
  
  # extract raw date from file name
  raw_date <- strsplit(filename, split='_')[[1]][2]
  date <- as.Date(raw_date, "%b%d_%Y")  # format as datetime
  
  # extract event from file name
  event <- strsplit(filename, split='_')[[1]][3]
  
  # extract speech and part from file
  content <- readChar(file, file.info(file)$size)
  speech <- content[grepl("^X1", content)]
  part <- content[grepl("^part", content)]
  
  # create a new observation (row)
  new_obs <- tibble(speech=speech, part=part, location=location, event=event, date=date)
  
  # append the new observation to the existing data
  biden_data <- bind_rows(biden_data, new_obs)
  
  rm(filename, location, raw_date, date, content, speech, part, new_obs, file)  # cleanup
}
```

Desired Output is supposed to look like this:

```
## # A tibble: 128 x 5
## speech                                         part   location event  date
## <chr>                                          <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  <date>
## 1 Folks, thanks for taking the time to be here~ Char~ Charlot~ Raci~ 2020-09-23
## 2 One of the things that really matters to me,~ Char~ Charlot~ Raci~ 2020-09-23
## 3 How people going to do that? And the way, in~ Char~ Charlot~ Raci~ 2020-09-23
## 4 In addition to that, we find ourselves in a ~ Char~ Charlot~ Raci~ 2020-09-23
## 5 If he had spoken, as I said, they said at Co~ Char~ Charlot~ Raci~ 2020-09-23
## 6 But what I want to talk to you about today i~ Char~ Charlot~ Raci~ 2020-09-23
## 7 And thirdly, if you’re a business person, le~ Char~ Charlot~ Raci~ 2020-09-23
## 8 For too many people, particularly in the Afr~ Char~ Charlot~ Raci~ 2020-09-23
## 9 It goes to education, as well as access to e~ Char~ Charlot~ Raci~ 2020-09-23
## 10 And then we’re going to talk about, I think ~ Char~ Charlot~ Raci~ 2020-09-23
## # ... with 118 more rows
```

Comment: What is the output of `list.files(path="./data/csv", pattern='*.txt', full.names=T)` ?

Comment: list.files(path="./data/csv", pattern='*.txt', full.names=T) checks all the files with .txt extension in that directory

Comment: I understand what it is supposed to do, but what does it actually return?

Comment: It return a character vector of the names of the six files in the "./data/csv" directory:          ./data/csv/Charlotte_Sep23_2020_Racial_Equity_Discussion-1.txt
./data/csv/Cleveland_Sep30_2020_Whistle_Stop_Tour.txt
./data/csv/Milwaukee_Aug20_2020_Democratic_National_Convention.txt
./data/csv/Philadelphia_Sep20_2020_SCOTUS.txt
./data/csv/Washington_Sep26_2020_US_Conference_of_Mayors.txt
./data/csv/Wilmington_Nov25_2020_Thanksgiving.txt

Answer (score 0):

Starting with a vector of file paths:

```r
files <- c("Charlotte_Sep23_2020_Racial_Equity_Discussion-1.txt", "Cleveland_Sep30_2020_Whistle_Stop_Tour.txt", "Milwaukee_Aug20_2020_Democratic_National_Convention.txt", "Philadelphia_Sep20_2020_SCOTUS.txt", "Washington_Sep26_2020_US_Conference_of_Mayors.txt", "Wilmington_Nov25_2020_Thanksgiving.txt")
```

We can capture the components into a frame:

```r
meta <- strcapture("^([^_]+)_([^_]+_[^_]+)_(.*)\\.txt$", files, list(location="", date="", event=""))
meta
#       location       date                          event
# 1    Charlotte Sep23_2020     Racial_Equity_Discussion-1
# 2    Cleveland Sep30_2020              Whistle_Stop_Tour
# 3    Milwaukee Aug20_2020 Democratic_National_Convention
# 4 Philadelphia Sep20_2020                         SCOTUS
# 5   Washington Sep26_2020        US_Conference_of_Mayors
# 6   Wilmington Nov25_2020                   Thanksgiving
```

And then iterate on that for the contents into a single frame.

```r
out <- do.call(Map, c(list(f = function(fn, ...) cbind(..., read.table(fn, header = TRUE))),
                      list(files), meta))
out <- do.call(rbind, out)
rownames(out) <- NULL
out[1:3,]
#    location       date                      event
# 1 Charlotte Sep23_2020 Racial_Equity_Discussion-1
# 2 Charlotte Sep23_2020 Racial_Equity_Discussion-1
# 3 Cleveland Sep30_2020          Whistle_Stop_Tour
#                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  X1
# 1 Folks, thanks for taking the time to be here today. I really appreciate it. And we even have an astronaut in our house and I tell you what, that’s pretty cool. Look, first of all, I want to thank Chris and the mayor for being here, and all of you for being here. You know, these are tough times. Over 200,000 Americans have passed away. Over 200,000, and the number is still rising. The impact on communities is bad across the board, but particularly bad for African-American communities. Almost four times as likely, three times as likely to catch the disease, COVID, and when it’s caught, twice as likely to die as white Americans. It’s sort of emblematic of the inequality that exists and the circumstances that exist.
# 2                                                                                                                                                 One of the things that really matters to me, is we could do … It didn’t have to be this bad. You have 30 million people on unemployment, you have 20 million people figuring whether or not they can pay their mortgage payment this month, and what they’re going to be able to do or not do as the consequence of that, and you’ve got millions of people who are worried that they’re going to be thrown out in the street because they can’t pay their rent. Although they’ve been given a reprieve for three months, but they have to pay double the next three months when it comes around.
# 3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               Charlotte_Sep23_2020_Racial_Equity_Discussion-1.txt
#               part
# 1 Charlotte_part_1
# 2 Charlotte_part_2
# 3        something
```

(I made fake files for all but the first file.)

Brief walk-through:

1. `strcapture` takes the regex (lots of `_`-separation) and creates a frame of location, date, etc.
2. `Map` takes a function with 1 or more arguments (we use two: `fn=` for the filename, and `...` for "the rest") and applies it to each of the subsequent lists/vectors. In this case, I'm using `...` to `cbind` (column-bind/concatenate) the columns from `meta` to what we read from the file itself. This is useful in that it combines the 1 row of each `meta` row with any-number-of-rows from the file itself. (We could have hard-coded `...` instead as `location`, `date`, and `event`, but I tend to prefer to generalize, in case you need to extract something else from the filenames.)
3. Because we use `...`, however, we need to combine `files` and the columns of `meta` in a list and then call our anon-function with the list contents as arguments.
4. The contents of `out` after our `do.call(Map, ...)` is in a `list` and not a single frame. Each element of this list is a frame with the same column-structure, so we then combine them by rows with `do.call(rbind, out)`.
5. R is going to use the names from `files` into row names, which I find unnecessary (and distracting), so I removed the row names. Optional.

---

If you're interested, this may appear much easier to digest using dplyr and friends:

```r
library(dplyr)
# library(tidyr) # unnest
out <- strcapture("^([^_]+)_([^_]+_[^_]+)_(.*)\\.txt$", files,
                  list(location="", date="", event="")) %>%
  mutate(contents = lapply(files, read.table, header = TRUE)) %>%
  tidyr::unnest(contents)
```